# nginx denying request based on domain name

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have a backend on Tomact and static content an angularjs app hosted on nginx reversed proxied.

I want to deny any requests apart from the authorized domains How can I achieve this with nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a default virtual host in nginx, which will deny requests.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: `server_name _;` is needless. Also `deny all` could be used without location (and I would prefer `return 403` or even `return 444`)

Comment: How would nginx know that request is from unauthorized domain ?

Comment: You define the authorized domains in another virtual server / other virtual servers. Then, nginx regards all other virtual hosts as unauthorized.